# What is the biblical basis for Antinomianism or extreme Grace?

Tags: biblical-basis, grace, antinomianism

What is the biblical basis for systematic Antinomianism, or, if you prefer, extreme Grace?

I am looking for someone with first hand knowledge of its teachings who can justify this view. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antinomianism#Opposing_Pauline_passages) lists verses of the Bible which seem to counter it. A good answer will  rebut those verses from an Antinomianist's perspective.

Comment: Related: [Do any Christian traditions claim to be antinomian?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4384/4188)

Comment: @caseyr547 You may look at [Free Grace Theology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_Grace_theology#Free_Grace_soteriology)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another term is "Gospel Reductionism".

> Therefore, there is now no condemnation for those who are in Christ Jesus. Romans 8:1
>
> For I resolved to know nothing while I was with you except Jesus Christ and him crucified. 1 Cor 2:2
>
> Whoever believes and is baptized will be saved, but whoever does not believe will be condemned. Mark 16:16

There are very few people who openly claim the name Antinomian. But I've met many who were effectively Antinomian in their faith walk.  In different cases, I've seen discussions of sin, social responsibility, and even good works "shut down" by repeating one of the three verses above.

In other words, "there is no condemnation" is read as "no need to examine my conscience."  "Knowing nothing but Christ" is read as "stop talking about knowing the needs of others." "Whoever is baptized" is read as "I'm baptized, stop talking about morality."

Answer (score 2):

On the article on Antinomianism.

Consider what is the Etymological root of Antinomian, a Hebraic term used by Jesus Christ in the Epistles as a heinous sin.  (Matthew. 7:23) "I never knew you; depart from me you that work‚ (Greek Strong # 458) ANTINOMIAN."

Let us peel off the theological bark and shine the spot light on this dogma to learn the bare truth of what Antinomianism is in the Greek Epistles (Strong # 458 Antanomia) what it really means.  Greek Strong # 458 Antanomia i.e. Anomia, meaning Antinomian i.e. Antinomianism.  As Jesus and others spoke about Antinomianism again occurs 16 times in the Epistles all as a public rebuke of sinful wickedness.

Just look at one (Matthew. 7: 21-23) Who are those that find themselves expelled by Jesus.? ? ?  Who are these people? ? ?  The Antinomians being talked about here that call Jesus “Lord” and even do good works in His name.  These are church Antinomians involved in church activities.  They expect to inherit eternal salvation, nevertheless find themselves expelled by Jesus from salvation.

In Greek one can use a singular “A” prefix letter to abbreviate for “no,” “not,” “without” and “ANTI.”  “A” prefix letter attached to a Greek word gives the word a negative meaning, just as “A” prefix letter attached to English words as Amoral, Atheist, etc.  The disposition exhibit in the meaning of this word is that those who consider themselves as antinomian are against IE anarchists of God’s Law, Scripture Law is the (Greek Strong's # 3551 NOMOS.)  Antinomianism is antithetical to God's scripture sovereignty.

(Lev. 4:2) express this reprimanded sin as “Against the Commandments of Yahweh.” or Anti-commandments.  The Torah (Hebrew Strong's # 8451) meaning scripture Law, is interchangeable with the (Greek Strong's # 3551 NOMOS) and the Greek NOMOS, is the word used by the translators of the Septuagint to translate the Hebrew word Torah.  As used in (Hosea. 8:1) “They transgressed My covenant and transgressed against My law.”  As Hosea express, Against Yahweh Covenant and Torah, is coined by the word Antinomian.

“Antinomian” has been alternative form of expression for over two millennia meaning against the scripture Lawgiver and His Law.  It’s from the term in the Epistles {Greek Strong # 458 Antanomia i.e. Anomia.}  (Heb. 1:9) “Love righteousness and hate (G Strong # 458) ANTINOMIAN.”

Comment: Anomia and Antinomia are two quite distinctly different words in koine greek. They were NEVER the sam word and NEVER were interchangeable. To claim as much is simply a self serving falsehood. It is the same in English where we have borrowed these same greek words to denote certain things
apathetic means without pathos. NOT against pathos as you would have us believe. Amora never means against morals. That would be antimoral or immoral depending on the context. Amoral simply means "without morals".